# GGplot for very large dataset with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataset with with more than 270000000.
The plot bellow does what I want, but the generated plots are to small to see.
How can I make my plots more readable?
(I was think of a solution like showing only the first 4 and have 11 plots in total then (41 plots in total divided by 4 is 10.25), but other solutions are also good) 
All the variables that I use in the plot are continues values.

```
library(ggplot2)    
CSV %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
      stat_summary2d(aes(z=ABCD), bins=30, na.rm=T) +
      coord_fixed() +
      scale_fill_viridis_c() +
      facet_wrap(~round(Z/1), ncol=5)
```

[image: the plot]

**Update**
This did not solve the issue:

```
CSV %>% filter(ABCD <= 11) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
  stat_summary2d(aes(z=ABCD), bins=30, na.rm=T) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  facet_wrap(~round(Z/1), ncol=5)
```

Comment: If you want to filter them, you can put a `CSV %>% filter(Z <= 11) %>%...` to have the first 11 facets only. Also, you can define your plot with `p <- your plot code` and use `plotly::ggplotly(p)` to zoom in each facet.

Comment: @s_t I updated my question, but this did not solve my issue, the plot stays the same. I am not using plotly because I am using knitr to create a PDF file

Comment: You should filter the variable you use for facetting (and my code should work with numeric variables). In your code you're filtering ABCD, but you facet by Z/1. If you want less facet, you'd filter the facet variable, in this case, Z/1.

Comment: @s_t Your are right indeed this works, how do i get number 12 till 20 for example?

Comment: You can do this  `...%>% filter(Z/1 >=  12 , Z/1 <= 20)...`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the question based on the idea of s_t

```
CSV %>% transform(ZR = round(Z)) %>% filter(ZR >= 10 & ZR <= 20) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y)) +
  stat_summary2d(aes(z=ABCD), bins=30, na.rm=T) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  facet_wrap(~round(Z/1), ncol=5)
```